# Clip or mask 'touchable' area of a UITableViewCell within a flexible width UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have an iOS app with a UITableView that has flexible width, which allow me to automatically place scrollbar on the right hand side of my iPad, during orientation change.

However, my cell view has a non resizable background which is supposed to show the user what the touchable area is. However, if the user touch far outside the background, the gesture is intercepted as a didSelect event, because the table is covering the whole screen, and so does the table cell.

I am therefore looking for a way to parse user touch, see if it is outside the background, and accept it or not.

To complicate things, I am using UIStoryBoard.

UPDATE:
just to complete the answer, of the two solutions suggested by lolcat, I have chosen to override the NSResponder method, because I have a UIStoryBoard in place with all the segues already drawn. By using the NSResponder I didn't change a line of code in my view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something like this by placing an invisible button over the cell where the touch should be intercepted. Create a function to respond as the selector to that button which will act like your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function normally would.

Otherwise you can subclass UITableViewCell and override touchesBegan (or touchesEnded - based on what you're looking for). This will allow you to see the exact point tapped within the cell. This method can be [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414464/iphone-custom-uitableviewcell-with-multiple-areas-that-respond-to-taps).

Comment: I cannot see a method like touchesBegin/End: in UITableViewCell, has it been deprecated ?

Comment: The touch functions are UIResponder functions. UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView which is a subclass of UIResponder. [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: ok, I see, there's a typo error in the answer you point, I just copied and paste and the compiler was complaining.